How can I get Typescript narrowing in this case?
The following code sets a property on an object from a form input. The name on the input will be the property and the value will be the target value.
This approach works without type errors when all properties of typeof draft are the same type (like string). But when the type has mixed properties, ie some with string, some bool, etc, I get the error below saying never.
Is there some narrowing or generic passing I could do to give TS what it needs for type safety here?
  const updateEditedRecord = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { target } = event;
    const val = target.value;

    setEditedRecord((draft) => {
      const name = target.name as keyof typeof draft;
      draft[name] = val; // => Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    });
  };


This doesn't seem like a [mre]; I can import React, but what's setEditedRecord? Ideally we'd be able to copy and paste your code into our own IDEs to see the issue directly without having to clear up unrelated problems. Could you please [edit] to do this?

You could make a helper function to narrow the type based on the property type like this:
function setProperty<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K, value: string) {
  const prop = obj[key];

  if (typeof prop === 'boolean') {
    obj[key] = (value === 'true') as T[K];
  } else if (typeof prop === 'number') {
    obj[key] = (Number(value)) as T[K];
  } else {
    obj[key] = value as T[K];
  }
}

const updateEditedRecord = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const { target } = event;
  const val = target.value;

  setEditedRecord((draft) => {
    const name = target.name as keyof typeof draft;
    setProperty(draft, name, val);
  });
};


This looks promising, I'll play with it.
